# What is the best way to replace string in while loop

Tags: java

What is the best way to replace a string in a while loop that reads lines from a file?

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
 if (line.contains("blabla")) {
  line = line.replaceAll("blabla", "eee");
 }
 writer.write(line);
}
```

is this correct way, I want to read all file lines, and check each line if contains this word, there is only one line that contains this word, if it contains it then replace this word and do not check another lines.

Comment: You could replace the string only in the end after reading the whole file. If you can make sure that `blabla` really only occurs at 1 point and nowhere else, then that would probably be better

Comment: You need to insert a `break;` as the last statement in your if-condition then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag as a condition in your while and update it in your if:

```
boolean found = false;
while ((!found) && ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
 if (found = line.contains("blabla")) {
  line = line.replaceAll("blabla", "eee");
 }
 writer.write(line);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the file contains about 200 lines, and it read each line and after that in the same while loop it write each line to another file. I would like to replace the word if the line it contains. After it replace it then to does not replace it, so I am asking that above code that is written is correct or not.

Comment: @Gstark your code is correct for the task that you have described as a comment here. You should do a few tests though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace this,

```
File your_file = new File(filePath)
String oldContent = “”;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(your_file));
String line = reader.readLine();

while (line != null)
{
 oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();
 line = reader.readLine();
}


String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll("wantToBeReplace", newString);

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(your_file);
writer.write(newContent);
reader.close();
writer.close();
```